# taking string input as parameter in constructor in OOP

Tags: c++, oop

This code is showing error when I make an instance of the class website. The instance has to use the explicit constructor which I have defined in the class definition. So I am passing a string value in it. This value is being received by an array of character type in the constructor which then initializes a pointer pointing to that array. Please avoid giving complex answers.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>
using namespace std;

class Links
{
private:
    char *linkname;
public:
    Links()
    {
        cout << "Links default constructor called." << endl;
    };
    Links(char n[]):linkname(n)
    {
        cout << "Links parameterized constructor called." << endl;
    };
    char getlinkname()
    {
        return *linkname;
    }
    void setlinkname(char n[])
    {
        linkname = n;
    }
};

class Webpage
{
private:
    double width;
    double height;
    Links link1;
    Links link2;
public:
    Webpage()
    {
        cout << "Webpage default constructor called." << endl;
    };
    Webpage(double w, double h) :width(w), height(h)
    {
        cout << "Webpage parameterized constructor called." << endl;
    };
    double getheight()
    {
        return height;
    }
    double getwidth()
    {
        return width;
    }
    void setheight(double h)
    {
        height = h;
    }
    void setwidth(double w)
    {
        width = w;
    }
};

class Website
{
private:
    char *name;
    Webpage webpage1{24.5,37.2};
    Webpage webpage2;
    Webpage webpage3{10,18.7};
    Webpage webpage4;
public:
    Website()
    {
        cout << "Website default constructor called." << endl;
    };
    Website(char n[]):name(n)
    {
        cout << "Website parameterized constructor called." << endl;
    };
    char getname()
    {
        return *name;
    }
    void setname(char n[])
    {
        name = n;
    }

};

int main()
{
    Website w1("www.google.com");
    
    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I get a warning `ISO C++ forbids converting a string constant to 'char*'`. Have you tried fixing that?

Comment: Are you aware of the built-in `std::string`?

Comment: By the way, by ignoring the warning, I could compile & run this code without a problem. What error message do you get? (I did remove  conio.h)

Comment: Using `std::string` will make it work out-of-the-box. If you insist on `char*`, you will have to code a lot more to assure correct copying of C-style strings.

Comment: @balping I didn't get that error. The error is
E0289 no instance of constructor "Website::Website" matches the argument list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

String literals are 'const', try this:

```
class Website
{
private:
    const char *name;
    Webpage webpage1{24.5,37.2};
    Webpage webpage2;
    Webpage webpage3{10,18.7};
    Webpage webpage4;
public:
    Website()
    {
        cout << "Website default constructor called." << endl;
    };
    Website(const char* n):name(n)
    {
        cout << "Website parameterized constructor called." << endl;
    };
    const char* getname()
    {
        return name;
    }
    void setname(const char* n)
    {
        name = n;
    }

};
```

Comment: Yeah this works fine for an instance of website but it still doesn't function for an instance of Link. Can you please help me with that too.
The error says "expected a type specifier "

Comment: Although, I've managed to correct the remaining code but I want to know the reason. I actually used curly brackets rather than round brackets for the instance of class Links but I want to know that why it didn't work with round brackets?